# CFA on non-normal ordinal data

Tags: r-lavaan

I hope you are doing well,

I'm taking my first steps in R and the Lavaan Package, and I'm trying to investigate the factorial structure of a measure related to dating victimization. The sample consists of 957 participants without missing values. The response options use a 5-point Likert scale. Both univariate and multivariate normalities are violated.

Here is the model, along with the outputs and warning messages.

Model.

Four first-order factor structure

model <- '

f1 =~ TV1 + TV2 + TV3 + TV4 + TV5 + TV6 + TV7 + TV8 + TV9 + TV10

f2 =~ TV11 + TV12 + TV13 + TV14 + TV15 + TV16 + TV17

f3 =~ TV18 + TV19 + TV20 + TV21 + TV22+ TV23 + TV24 + TV25

f4 =~ TV26 + TV27 + TV28 + TV29+ TV30'

fit.model <- cfa(model, data = TARV, ordered = TRUE, estimator = "DWLS", se = "robust", test = "scaled.shifted", std.lv = TRUE)

summary(fit.model, std = TRUE, fit.measures = TRUE)

Output:

lavaan 0.6.16 ended normally after 34 iterations

Estimator                                       DWLS

Optimization method                           NLMINB

Number of model parameters                       185

Number of observations                           957

Model Test User Model:

```
                                          Standard      Scaled
```

Test Statistic                               381.267     617.183

Degrees of freedom                               399         399

P-value (Chi-square)                           0.730       0.000

Scaling correction factor                                  1.083

Shift parameter                                          265.087

```
simple second-order correction
```

Model Test Baseline Model:

Test statistic                            142505.191   17287.640

Degrees of freedom                               435         435

P-value                                        0.000       0.000

Scaling correction factor                                  8.430

User Model versus Baseline Model:

Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    1.000       0.987

Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       1.000       0.986

Robust Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                            NA

Robust Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                               NA

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

RMSEA                                          0.000       0.024

90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.000       0.020

90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.009       0.028

P-value H_0: RMSEA <= 0.050                    1.000       1.000

P-value H_0: RMSEA >= 0.080                    0.000       0.000

Robust RMSEA                                                  NA

90 Percent confidence interval - lower                        NA

90 Percent confidence interval - upper                        NA

P-value H_0: Robust RMSEA <= 0.050                            NA

P-value H_0: Robust RMSEA >= 0.080                            NA

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

SRMR                                           0.041       0.041

I am getting this warning message:

Warning message:

In lav_model_vcov(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  :

lavaan WARNING:

```
The variance-covariance matrix of the estimated parameters (vcov)

does not appear to be positive definite! The smallest eigenvalue

(= -5.592776e-16) is smaller than zero. This may be a symptom that

the model is not identified.
```

I did run these functions, and I am getting these outputs:

> lavInspect(fit.model, "cov.lv")

```
  f1    f2    f3    f4
```

f1 1.000

f2 0.854 1.000

f3 0.922 0.816 1.000

f4 0.903 0.873 0.937 1.000

> det(lavInspect(fit.model, "cov.lv"))

[1] 0.003425802

> eigen(lavInspect(fit.model, "cov.lv"))

eigen() decomposition

$values

[1] 3.6536666 0.1999477 0.0990346 0.0473511

$vectors

```
       [,1]       [,2]          [,3]       [,4]
```

[1,] -0.5036916  0.1988844  0.7828187299  0.3064875

[2,] -0.4841475 -0.8386756 -0.0007780208 -0.2494471

[3,] -0.5033330  0.4944816 -0.1812847326 -0.6850399

[4,] -0.5084800  0.1120542 -0.5952563117  0.6120146

What can I do to find out the origin of these messages and solve the problem?

Are the DWLS, robust and scaled.shifted correct for the scale type and sample size? Or should I change for MLM, robust and satorra.bentler?

Does the chi-square statistic and is p-value compromise the model?

I'm sorry if these seem like really basic questions.

Thank you,

Maria

Answer (score 0):

The message is telling you to check `vcov()`, which is the covariance matrix of the estimated parameters, not of the variables.

```
vcov(fit.model)
```

The message means that some of your parameters have (multi)collinear sampling distributions.  This is probably because your sample size is too small to reliable model so many 5-category variables.  You can try not setting the `ordered=` argument, so it treats the 5 categories as numerical values, but set `estimator = "MLR"` to correct for nonnormality.

When you set `ordered = TRUE`, lavaan automatically sets the `estimator=`, `se=`, and `test=` arguments.